# Trying to combine InputBox and indexOf to find text in a single column and make active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have the user input text like , 9188675309 in the input box and store that into searchstring variable.

Then it needs to scan the entire column of R which is formatted to look like (918) 867-5309

If the user puts in 5309 or 86753 can it also find the matches?

If any or all matches are found and then highlight the whole row,

```
function seekAndselect(){
  var searchString = Browser.inputBox("Search For Phone Number?");
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  cell.setBackground('#ffff55');// replace by cell.setBackground(null); to reset the color when "leaving" the cell
  var activeR = cell.getRow()-1;
  var activeC = cell.getColumn()-1;
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var step = 0
  for(var r=0;r<data.length;++r){
    for(var c=0;c<data[0].length;++c){
      step++
      Logger.log(step+' -- '+searchString+'  =  '+data[r][c]);
      if(data[r][c]==''||step==1){ continue };
      if(searchString.toString().toLowerCase()==data[r][c].toString().toLowerCase()){
        ss.setActiveSelection(r+1,c+1);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will there be more than one match? It was a bit unclear. If there could be more than one match, then loop through the `R` column and [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the input/values. This way also allows for partial matches.

```
function seekAndselect(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  // User input
  var searchString = Browser.inputBox("Search For Phone Number?");
  // Remove non numbers
  var clean_search = searchString.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  // Get the R column values
  var r_col = ss.getRange(1, 18, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // Search each row in col R for a match and highlight the row
  r_col.forEach(function (e, i) {
    // Remove non numbers from data before matching
    if (e[0].replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").match(clean_search)) {
      var found_range = ss.getRange((i + 1), 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn())
      // Highlights the row from col A to R
      found_range.setBackground('#ffff55') 
      // Sets the active selection to the last matched row from col A to R
      ss.setActiveSelection(found_range)
    }
  });
}
```

I wasnt sure what you wanted with the `setActiveSelection()`, if there are multiple matches it will only select the last one. Also, if there are a lot of matches, this could take a long time to run, possibly even time-out. If that happens, a [batchUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) would be needed

Comment: Perfect!

Since it changes the background if it is found, how do you undo the background change? Another function to run ?

The `setactive` is to move the active cell to Column A + row # so it will move focus down or up based on where the row is found.

Comment: Upon further testing...

If I click OK without any value in the box, it will change the entire sheet to background yellow.

Need to add an error check or for loop until it is no longer "" or cancel.

Also, I am using odd(row) conditional formatting of blue. So if this row is highlighted yellow, but it is an odd row, it will stay blue. I thought of removing conditional formatting, but then would have to reapply all conditional formatting to the entire sheet. I have 10 conditions for various things to track.

Comment: add a `if (searchString == 'cancel')` check on the [inputBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox(String)). Also, conditional formatting generally wins in my experience. And to clear the background, another method would be needed and then some action to trigger it

Comment: `while(searchString == "")
  {
    try{
      var searchString = Browser.inputBox("Search For Phone Number?");
    }
    catch(e){
      continue;
    }
  } `

Fixed that.

And `if (clean_search == ""){return;}` fixed the highlight all rows thing. ASLO `function resetSearch(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var last_row = DataSheet.getLastRow();
  var target_range = DataSheet.getRange("A3"+":AE"+(last_row));
  target_range.setBackground(null)
}` to fix the reset all backgrounds